# What did they say in this ad?

Tags: listening

I am unable to make out what the actress said in this AAMI Insurance Ad: [Prove who's the better driver! #driverduels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j0c4JfXwd3U) (Before the other actor said "What are the chances?")

I would appreciate if anyone can tell me what she said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you think anyone is saying *"What are the chances?"*

The girl on the scooter says, ***"Read'em an' weep boys."***

Then the red-headed man says *"Loretta Jones"* which is a reference to others advertisements in this marketing campaign.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry, not a native speaker so I probably got it very wrong. So did the male actor say if he did not utter 'what are the chances'?

Comment: Not sure why anyone thinks the guy is saying anything about "chances".  He's saying "Loretta Jones!"  which is a tie in with an earlier ad when he eats her lunch.

Answer (score 3):

Note:  "Read [th]em and weep, boys" is a humorous phrase used when revealing a winning poker hand.  (Literally: look at my cards, and then cry because you realize you have lost the game.)

Comment: And, by extension, in many other domains when you want to declare victory.

Answer (score 0):

At the end he says:
"Never had a chance".